# Correct Count for Inventory System / Quest System

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for the random title. But basically:

I allow users to go on Quests stored in `user_quests`. The quest may ask the user to get several items and they are stored in `user_quest_items`.

Structure:

user_quests [ID, userid, timestamp]

user_quest_items [ID, userquestid, itemid, amount_needed]

Now I'm trying to run a single query to find out whether the user has the needed amount of items in their inventory so I can just display it to the user. I.e.

Find Green Apple [2 / 4]

My Inventory system allows for different instances of the same item. The structure:

items [ID, itemname, description, rarity]

item_instance [ID, itemid, special_details]

inventory [ID, userid, item_instanceid, quantity]

So basically, my query needs to calculate whether the items the quest asks for are in the user's inventory.  My current query is:

```
SELECT items.itemname, inventory.quantity, item_instances.ID as instanceid,
item_instances.itemid as instance_itemid, user_quest_items.itemid FROM 
user_quest_items
INNER JOIN items ON items.ID = user_quest_items.itemid
INNER JOIN user_quests ON user_quests.ID = user_quest_items.userquestid
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory ON inventory.userid = user_quests.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_instances ON item_instances.ID = inventory.item_instanceid AND item_instances.itemid = user_quest_items.itemid
WHERE user_quest_items.userquestid = 27
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I assume it's to do with the left outer join of inventory, but basically it is getting all items in the user's inventory rather than the specific ones asked by user_quest_items.

This works if I change item_instances to INNER JOIN, but the issue becomes then that if the user has 0 of the required items, no rows are returned which would make the user think they are not being asked for items. In that use case, I need it to say:

Green Apple [0 / 4]

Apologies for the complicated post. There are other reasons for making the inventory system instance based (I could definitely make it simpler but I need it this way for other mechanics).

Comment: Do the INNER JOINs between user_quest_items, items , and user_quests give you just the items for the quest you need? I'd strip the query back so that section works and then add in inventory next, followed by item_instances.

Comment: Yep, those queries work fine outside of the item check. I can do that no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can include *items* that don't exist.  You can, however, include the user id even if there are no items.  You would do that by starting a chain of `left join`s for that user:

```
SELECT u.userquestid,
       i.itemname, iv.quantity, ii.ID as instanceid,
       ii.itemid as instance_itemid, uqi.itemid
FROM (SELECT 27 as userquestid) u LEFT JOIN
     user_quest_items uqi
     ON u.userquestid = u.userquestid LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON i.ID = uqi.itemid LEFT JOIN
     user_quests uq
     ON uq.ID = uqi.userquestid LEFT JOIN
     inventory iv
     ON iv.userid = uq.userid LEFT JOIN
     item_instances ii
     ON ii.ID = iv.item_instanceid AND
       ii.itemid = uqi.itemid;
```